# gTTS Doesn't Save MP3 Files

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, google-text-to-speech

I want to create an artificial intelligence program using Python. I found out that I need gTTS but it doesn't save mp3 files. Help me, please.

```
#gtts is imported
def talkToMe(audio, lgg = 'en'):
    #print(audio)
    tts = gTTS(text = audio, lang = lgg)
    #tts.save('audio.mp3') #doesn't work
    with open("audio.mp3") as fp: #doesn't work
        tts.write_to_fp(fp)
    os.system('mpg123\mpg123.exe audio.mp3')
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\zigzag\Desktop\gtts_test1\main.py", line 9, in <module>
    talkToMe("hello")
  File "C:\Users\zigzag\Desktop\gtts_test1\main.py", line 7, in talkToMe
    tts.write_to_fp(fp)
  File "B:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gtts\tts.py", line 187, in write_to_fp
    part_tk = self.token.calculate_token(part)
  File "B:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py", line 28, in calculate_token
    seed = self._get_token_key()
  File "B:\Python36\lib\site-packages\gtts_token\gtts_token.py", line 62, in _get_token_key
    a = re.search("a\\\\x3d(-?\d+);", tkk_expr).group(1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Comment: does anything here help? https://github.com/pndurette/gTTS/issues/90

Comment: B4 asking here I looked at this post but it didn't help me (((

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from gtts import gTTS    
#gtts is imported
audio = 'Hello , I am Tina, your digital assistant'
def talkToMe(audio, lgg = 'en'):
    #print(audio)
    tts = gTTS(text = audio, lang = lgg)
    tts.save('audio.mp3') #doesn't work
    return None
talkToMe(audio , lgg ='en')
```

save the above file as text_2_speech.py (as an e.g.).i have tried it and it is working fine.  from command line type python -W ignore text_2_speech.py and then the file is saved as audio.mp3 in the current directory.

Comment: also you can try. pip uninstall gTTs-token , which will uninstall gtts-token version==1.1.1. and thn again do pip install gTTs-token which will install new version of gTTs-token==1.1.2